# Как сохранить Unity WebGL игру на жёсткий диск?

Tags: unity3d

Не могу понять структуру Unity WebGL игр, выложенных на игровых сайтах (прим. http://vseigru.net/igry-gonki/22418-igra-tryuki-na-gonochnykh-mashinakh-2.html). В сорцах вижу кучу .js файлов + различные .data файлы, однако при сохранении всего этого на винт и локальном запуске вываливаются куча ошибок. Я так понимаю, они где-то берут файлы с исходниками игр и потом конвертят это всё через Unity3D в формат WebGL?

Comment: Вопрос актуален?)

Answer (score 0):

При локальном запуске в браузерах действуют некоторые ограничения, так что для запуска надо поднимать свой веб-сервер.